# Why the restriction on parameter type and count on EventSource Methods

Tags: c#, trace, etw-eventsource

I am experimenting at the moment with Microsoft EventSources in C#.
One restriction is the following

> ...The number and types of arguments passed to the ETW method must
>   exactly match the types passed to the WriteEvent overload it calls.
>   For example:

```
[Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Informational)] 
public void Info(string message, int count) 
{
   base.WriteEvent(2, message, count); 
}
```

This basically limits you to writing a more rich API in the EventSource class. This basically means you can not create a method which receives a Custom Object and within the method body you can serialize it to a string (or another type supported by WriteEvent overloads).

The only thing you can decide is the method name and the parameternames and count which mirror an WriteEvent overloads.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: It may be worth trying out a later version of EventSource, specifically the Rich Data support: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2015/09/20/rich-payload-data-in-eventsource-v4-6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is required to build the manifest file. The`_EventSourceUsersGuide.docx` explains it:

> Event methods must match exactly the types of the WriteEvent overload it calls, in particular you should avoid implicit scalar conversions; they are dangerous **because the manifest is generated based on the signature of the ETW event method**, but the values passed to ETW are based on the signature of the WriteEvent overload.

Answer (score 13):

This was explained by magicandre1981. However, you are not prevented from writing the rich API you describe. The solution is to provide overloads marked with the NonEventAttribute. For example:

```
        [NonEvent]
        public void Warning(int tracerId, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (args != null)
                message = string.Format(message, args);
            Warning(tracerId, message);
        }

        [Event(EventIds.Warning, Level = EventLevel.Warning)]
        public void Warning(int tracerId, string message)
        {
            WriteEvent(EventIds.Warning, tracerId, message); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that help me resolve a "bad" example in the "Developer's Guide to Microsoft Enterprise Library - 2nd Edition" @page 130. Or maybe I missed something in their explanation.